# When a Permutation is not a cycle

Tags: terminology, permutations

$\sigma = \pmatrix{1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\3 &8 &6 &7 &4 & 1 & 5 & 2} = (136)(28)(475)$

I just have a question about terminology. Would it be correct to say that $\sigma$ is not a cycle but $\sigma$ is a product of 3 disjoint cycles?

Comment: I believe your last cycle should be (475). Also, yes.

Comment: @JacobSchlather: Fixed and thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @Jacob: Would you like to post an answer so the question can be listed as resolved?

Comment: @ZevChonoles Done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it would be to correct to say that $\sigma$ is a product of $3$ disjoint cycles.